# Express session cookie not saved in browser in production but works just fine in development

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

When I'm working on a local server I can save session cookie in browser but once it is deployed, not only is the session not persistent despite saving it req.session.save(), but it just never shows up on the application tab

I have tried setting samesite to none played around with cookie configuration and it won't work in production still

```
//my session config:

sessionConfig = {
store,
name: 'inspector',
secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET || 'iamintrouble',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    expires: Date.now() * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    sameSite: 'none',
    secure: true
}
}

app.use(session(sessionConfig));

//route to set session.user as logged in after login :
module.exports.loggedIn = async(req, res) => {
const user = await User.find({ username: req.body.username });
req.session.user = user;
req.session.save(err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        //session is saved here but doesn't persists after redirect
        res.redirect('https://snitcherapp.herokuapp.com')
    }
})
}

//route called on mount of root component to get loggedIn user

module.exports.isLogged = async(req, res) => {
console.log(req.session) //by this line the session is lost
if (req.session.user) {
    res.send({ loggedIn: true, user: req.session.user })
} else {
    res.send({ loggedIn: false })
}
}
```